# console login hangs on "Last login" line

Tags: linux, login, busybox

I'm logging in as root to an embedded system running Linux, on the console, as root.  After issuing the "Last Login" line, the console hangs.  It echoes any characters I type but otherwise I get no response.  If I hit ^C, I'm back to the login prompt, which implies that the login session has not yet started.

Any clues to what might be going wrong here?  I believe that rebooting will recover, and if not, re-imaging via USB is an issue, but I want to get to the root of what's happening here to fix the underlying problem.

The system runs bash/busybox for sessions, if that helps.  I'm not sure what linux distro; it's obfuscated by the manufacturer.

The "Last login" timestamp is being updated each time I try to log in.

In this case, networking is not configured so I can't try ssh.

Comment: Look at your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, ...

Comment: @IporSircer Yeah, the "usual suspects".  Since I can't log in, I can't check these, and it's unlikely someone changed them but will do after reboot.  However, on another identical system, if I put "sleep 60" in these, login, and ^C, I get to the shell, not back to the login prompt.  So I think it's something else.

Comment: Also, control-Z doesn't put the process in the background, as it does when there's a delay in a profile.  It just echoes as `^Z`.

Comment: I believe the underlying cause turned out to be a stale NFS handle used in the system standard profile or somewhere like that.  Sigh ... the people who wrote that should have known better!